# Grouping only by date in a varchar column in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, varchar

I have a mysql column where the data is stored as `VARCHAR` though the data values are of `datetime` in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.
Now my task is to group by the date part i.e `yyyy-mm-dd` by converting `VARCHAR` to date-time and then just taking date part out of it

**QUERY**

```
SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY name , [date part of the varchar field]
```

Please let me know if this is at all possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `left` function.  You can leave the `date` as a string:

```
SELECT left(datecol, 10) as YYYYMMDD, SUM(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY left(datecol, 10);
```

I removed `name` from the `group by` because it doesn't seem relevant to the question.  You can, of course, add it back in.

By the way, MySQL understands this format for dates, so if you really, really want a date:

```
SELECT date(left(datecol, 10)) as RealDate, SUM(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY RealDate;
```

Comment: this works as expected, i included name column in select, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your data in this `varchar` field is properly formatted, you can work with the [`left`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function, like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(mydate, 10) AS myval, 
       SUM(myvalue)
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY myval;
```

If this isn't a big issue; I'd advise converting your `varchar` column to `datetime` or `timestamp`. If not only for the possibly better data [storage usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html), it'll be way easier to do work with [date and time related functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks @Bjoem , shall i store date and time as same fields or seperate fields and if seperate, what would be the datatype of each of them (or both would have same data type of datetime) ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the data. In my applications I usually have to calculate with those fields, therefore `datetime` is mostly my choice. Read about this here and make up your mind. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html